# Where can I purchase Tier 1 Woodworking Recipes?

Tags: lord-of-the-rings-online

I'm levelling up another alt with the Woodworking craft skill but I seem to be unable to find any Tier 1 woodworking recipes. There's none in the auction house on my server and the Novice Woodworker in the Bree crafting hall only sells Tier 2 and Tier 3 recipes.

Where can I purchase the Tier 1 recipes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, to the best of my knowledge, you can't buy T1 recipes for any craft.

You will automatically have most of the recipes you need as soon as you choose your profession, but all remaining T1 recipes are loot drops from low level mobs on the landscape.